# SQL Server Management Studio changes characters of a string literal in update query

Tags: ssms

I'm running a simple update query in Mgmt studio: update mytable set name='Alış' where id=1. Query runs OK but I see that record is updated as name='Alis'. Turkish characters are changed to English!

I see from the connection properties that Server Language is English (United States) and Collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. But I see other records with name='Alış' entered from our 3rd party application, so server can store turkish characters.

So it must be mgmt studio which changes the literal in my query. How can I run my update sql?

Comment: try some thing like `update mytable set name=N'Alış' `

Comment: @user1666620 but if string is prefix with char 'N' this shows that subsequent string in UNICODE

Comment: @JaydipJ sorry my mistake, missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast string into UNICODE characters, so change your update query like

```
UPDATE mytable SET name=N'Alış' WHERE id=1
```

> If String is Preceded with N that shows the subsequent string in UNICODE. Or we Can say that 'N' Represents 'National Lang. Char. Set'

Comment: Thanks! Just being curious: Wouldn't it better for SSMS to render all string literals in queries as unicode? I believe many people might run into the same problem.

Comment: @CaginUludamar Yes you can . It is always better to render string as unicode